# WordPress white screen with "All Pages"

Tags: pages, fatal-error

When I login to my WordPress site using my admin account everything seems to be working fine. I click on posts it lists all of my posts, I click on plugins I see all of my plugins, etc. but for some reason when I click on "All Pages" I get a blank white screen. I can go into each page individually and edit without any issues.

When I originally migrated my site from my local machine to the live server I had an issue with my table prefix names. For example; in my wp_config file I called "mr_3b7CgBNQ_" as my table prefix name, but my tables were actually "mr_3b7cgbnq_". This worked fine in my local environment but on the live server everything was broken. I've gone through and did a find and replace on a few tables to replace the table prefix where it was incorrect.

Is it possible that there is a table prefix called somewhere in the posts?

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging, but I'm not receiving any error messages.

Comment: Do you have php errors hidden by any chance?

Comment: I disabled my plugins and I'm now receiving a memory error: Notice: Constant WP_MEMORY_LIMIT already defined in /public_html/wp-config.php on line 101 and Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1977

Comment: I was able to fix this by adjusting the memory_limit in php.ini from 32M to 64M.